# NSManagedObject with Category and Delegate

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I created a `NSManagedObject` called MapState.  I then created a category for it to call some methods and store some extra variables.

.h
    #import "MapStateDB.h"

```
@protocol MapStateDelegate;

@interface MapStateDB (MapState)

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MapStateDelegate> delegate;

-(void)selectedSceneObject:(SceneObject *)sceneObject;
-(void)removeDisplayedScene;

@end


@protocol MapStateDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)displayScene:(SceneDB *)scene inState:(NSString *)state;
-(void)removeScene:(SceneDB *)scene;

@end
```

In the .m:

```
@dynamic delegate;

-(void)setDelegate:(id<MapStateDelegate>)delegate {

}
```

How do I do the setter?  Normally it would just be:

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id<MapStateDelegate>)delegate {
    _delegate = delegate;
}
```

But since the variable is `@dynamic` instead of `@synthesize`, no `_delegate` is created. And `@synthesize` creates an error.

How should I be handling this?

Comment: You should probably handle this with a wrapper class instead of an extension...

Comment: Thats my second option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `@dynamic` implies that the appropriate accessors will be created at run time. `NSManagedObject` does that for attributes of entities in the data model, but not for properties you declare. You **could** do this with some ObjC runtime wizardry (the APIs all exist, and are supported, so it's not what might be called a hack) but it's not trivial. (Using `@dynamic` would be fine if `delegate` were a transient property on the entity, but that would mean that the delegate would have to be one of the types supported by Core Data instead of any class implementing the protocol).

But there's hope! If you're using Xcode 7+ to generate `NSManagedObject` subclasses, it's safe to add your own properties in the subclass without fear of them being overwritten. You'd make the `delegate` property work by adding a `@synthesize` for it and then not adding your own setter. You don't have to provide one unless you need to do more than just set the property value.

If you **do** need a custom setter, modify the `@synthesize` to be something like

```
@synthesize delegate = _delegate;
```

(you don't have to use `_delegate` here, any valid name is fine)

Then add a setter like the one in your question that assigns to the synthesized name.

Comment: Please be aware that adding properties to `NSManagedObject`s can be an exercise in frustration, as the lifetime of such an object is not entirely under your control.  If you have exactly one `NSManagedObjectContext` in your app, you'd be safe retaining references to your objects.  However, only the most trivial of apps are setup that way.

Comment: I subclassed my `NSManagedObject` and it seems to work.  I can `@synthesize delegate = _delegate` and it works great, thank you!  @Avi: I am aware if a context becomes nil, the temporary managed objects will cease to exist.  I do have a main/default context as well as temporary contexts that save against the main context when a saving action is made.

Comment: I'm running into an issue where I can not instantiate the class. I started a separate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34049208/creating-a-subclass-of-a-nsmanagedobject.