# Creating a Subclass of a NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I have a subclassed `NSManagedObject` class:

```
@interface MapStateDB : NSManagedObject

@end
```

Now I want to make a subclass of `MapStateDB` class:

.h

```
@interface MapState : MapStateDB

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <MapStateDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MapState

@synthesize delegate = _delegate;

@end
```

Except when I try to create a `MapState` object, it fails:

```
MapState *mapState = [MapState MR_createEntityInContext:context];

DLog(@"mapState: %@", mapState);
```

output:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController testStuff] | mapState: (null)
```

I can create a `MapStateDB" object just fine:

```
MapStateDB *mapStateDB = [MapStateDB MR_createEntityInContext:context];
DLog(@"mapStateDB: %@", mapStateDB);
```

output:

```
DEBUG | -[LoginViewController testStuff] | mapStateDB: <MapStateDB: 0x7d432d00> (entity: MapStateDB; id: 0x7d424640 <x-coredata:///MapStateDB/tF842754F-4044-44E5-A9D5-118389ABF4AA2>
```

The original intent is to provide a delegate to a `NSManagedObject` and was suggested in another question to subclass my `NSManagedObject`: [NSManagedObject with Category and Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831000/nsmanagedobject-with-category-and-delegate)

Any ideas why the subclassed `MapState` object isn't being created?

EDIT:

I replaced the Magical Record method `[MR_createEntityInContext:]` with the Objective-C standard `[insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]`:

```
MapState *mapState2 = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MapState" inManagedObjectContext:context];
DLog(@"mapState2: %@", mapState2);
```

output:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'MapState' in this model.'
```

So Magical Record was catching the error and returning `nil`.  So I guess @Rickster's question is pointing to the issue, my Core Data model has no idea what `MapState` is.

Could I make a transient property for the delegate? OR should I just use a wrapper class?

Is it possible to get a `NSManagedObject` with a delegate property?

EDIT 2:

I tried changing the MapStateDB entities' class to FooMapState:

[image]

I used Xcode to create the subclassed `NSManagedObject` and it created FooMapState.h/.m files (instead of just MapState.h/.m files):

```
@interface FooMapState : NSManagedObject

@end
```

The FooMapState and MapState are identical, just with different names.  They are both subclassed `NSManagedObject` which makes creating a delegate difficult (back to the original question I posted).

Comment: Is there a corresponding sub-entity for the subclass in your xcdatamodel?

Comment: Are you asking if there is a `MapState` in the data model?  No, there is not.  If I did, I believe I would run into the same issue when trying to created a delegate property.

Comment: Since you have the source code to Magical Record, now would be a good time to step through `MR_createEntityInContext` (and whatever methods it calls) to see what's causing it to return nil.

Comment: I replaced the Magical Record method with the default creating method: `[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]` and I get the error "+entityForName: could not locate an entity named 'MapState' in this model". Will update question.

Comment: You won't really be able to do what you're trying to do.  When creating a new entity, Core Data will always create a class of the type specified in the model.  There's no mechanism to instantiate an entity and specify the class name it should be created as.  You can play around with entity inheritance, but it's not good to abuse the feature just to fake inheritance.

Comment: By the way, what use case do you have for a model object requiring a delegate?  `NSManagedObject`s aren't quite POOCOs (plain old objective-c objects), but they should still be pretty dumb.  A delegate property implies they do stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You're having problems because you're trying to create an instance of the entity `MapState`, but there is no such entity in your data model-- the entity name is `MapStateDB`.

It's OK to have the `MapState` subclass, but in order for creating instances to work, you need to set the right class name for the entity in your data model. So on the `MapStateDB` entity, set the class name to `MapState` (You can type any class name there, really). Then when you create a new instance of the `MapStateDB` entity, you'll get an instance of the `MapState` class.